"'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found "error while configuring flutter_sharing_intent: in ios
> Error (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
.../ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:9:8

Error (Xcode): failed to emit precompiled header
'...Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dsnptuajxrfhfkaeeeuftyzcmelt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/Runner-Bridging-Header-swift
_2EYJEAA4R74FW-clang_19A6TBQEA2120.pch' for bridging header '...ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h'

Encountered error while building for device.

i was trying to build ios app but after completing ios configuration for flutter_sharing_intent I am getting above error

Step 1:
Open Finder in Mac and go
/Users/[u r system name]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
Step 2:
clear the all derived data.
Step 3:
pod deintegreate(uninstalling pods)
Step 4:
Install pods
Finally run the project from Xcode.
I hope this will help.
